# Stripe upgrade plan error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using "laravel/cashier": "~6.0" in my application. I have two stripe plan . When i try to upgrade my plan its show this error:

[this is error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSnre.png)

Comment: u might want to edit ur question because there isnt any image

Comment: @flex i add a error image link

Comment: the error is pretty self explanatory.. you are calling a method that doesnt exist maybe show us the code so we can help u?

Comment: @flex i  pass this function  in  post request:  $user->subscription('main')->swap($request->plan);